# My Sql Delete statement is being interpreted wrong

Tags: c#, sql

This could just be me looking at it wrong, but I need another persons eyes to look at it cause I can't see it.

why is this:

```
comm.CommandText = "Delete from COURSE where COURSE_NAME='" + theCourse.CourseName() + "';"; // create query
```

outputting the quotation at the end instead of '

result:

```
Delete from COURSE where COURSE_NAME='LEARNING VITALS"
```

Comment: SQL injection detected.

Comment: Try changing it to use a parameterized query, instead.  Not only would it likely fix your problem, but it would also prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Maybe the `CourseName()` method is returning a string with a trailing quote.

Comment: Use debugger to see what is the value in `theCourse.CourseName()`

Comment: it has no quotations in debugger

Comment: Where did you get the result from?

Comment: down in the debugger when it breaks.... even if it has a quote in it though wouldn't it still have the ' at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay don't ask me why or how but when you space the ";" from the quotation mark the ' appears and the " disappears and it works.

edited code:

```
comm.CommandText = "Delete from COURSE where COURSE_NAME='" + theCourse.CourseName() + "'; ";
```

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT!!! concatenate strings when you build sql statements, that way you're open for sql injection attacks http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp. Use parameters instead.

```
comm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM Course WHERE Course_Name=@name";
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "theNameOfTheCourse");
```

Comment: Good advice, but it is not the answer

Comment: yes this is good it doesn't fix my issue. I have changed to this though so thank you for the info.